# Docker pull fail/Gitlabci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have encountered a problem a few days ago and it drives me crazy. I have few  services running on gitlab-ci.
A few days ago when, i tried to i run "docker-compose pull" or "docker pull image:version" and it failed. The weird thing is that nothing changed and it worked so far. For some services it says pull access denied because it requires docker login or repository does not exist. I run docker login before making pull, images exist and repository too. I don't understand. This is what happens when I run docker-pull compose. Docker pull is a success for some of them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3wMr.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly logged in?

Comment: is it happening for this one specific repository or with  other repos also?

Comment: Yes I'm correctly logged in

Comment: It's happening with 9 of my 15 services by just this project

Comment: ok. if its happening with this repo/project it means docker login and other permission are fine. possibility are that you have lost permission on this repo to pull, which gilab manage through role and API. could you verify that still you have valid permission on the project.